# How to send a local file path thorugh the QnA Create Knowledgebase API?

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am referring to this [QnA create knowledgebaseAPI](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da75ff) documentation. I want to upload the knowledge base through the Excel file which is stored in the local path. I don't have URL for the excel file, only the local path.

I followed the code given on [github link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-qnamaker-csharp/blob/master/create-knowledge-base.cs), I removed the unnecessary things and kept the variable "kb" as shown below:

```
   static string kb = $@"
    {{
      'name': 'VivekKB',
      'qnaList': [],
      'urls': [ ],
      'files': [
            'files': {{DBFile}}
        ]
    }}
```

**DBFile** is the filename with full path. When I run the code, it creates an Empty knowledge store. It doesn't upload the excel file which I mentioned. Can you please help me to figure it out how to upload a local excel QnA data directly to QnA store. I want to avoid manual uploading excel to knowledgebases at https://www.qnamaker.ai.

Thanks in advance. 
Vivek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connected with the QnA team directly, asking the following:

Question: Is it possible to use a local file path to create KB through the programmatic API?

I know given in the programmatic QnA API docs it demonstrates how to add a PDF file that’s already also available online as well:

```
"files": [
    {
      "fileName": "SurfaceManual.pdf",
      "fileUri": "https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/9/B/29B20383-302C-4517-A006-B0186F04BE28/surface-pro-4-user-guide-EN.pdf"
    }
```

However when I tried using “POST Create Knowledgebase “ in Postman using the relative file path in the “fileUri”, I get “invalid uri” error.

Request Body

```
{
  "name": "Simple QnA",
  "files": [
    {
      "fileName": "simpleQnaSource.docx",
      "fileUri": "C:\\Users\\v-asho\\Documents\\RandomWordDocs"
    }
  ]
}
```

Response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadArgument",
        "message": "Invalid input. See details.",
        "details": [
            {
                "code": "ValidationFailure",
                "message": "File Uri has one or more invalid uri.",
                "target": "Files[0].FileUri"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Uploading the `.docx` file online through qnamaker.ai portal successfully creates a KB, it’s specifically through the programmatic api where I’m having issues.

---

QnA Team's Answer:

**“`fileUri`” can have a publicly available and downloadable URI as value.
When using it via API, please upload the contents of local file to a publicly available domain. (Example: Azure storage blob shared to public).**

Comment: Thanks, @Zeryth. Finally, I had to use the blob too.